# Finding an orthonormal basis for the set of vectors.

Tags: vectors, orthogonality, orthonormal

I'm studying on the following problem. I have a set of four vectors such as 
v1 = (2, −1, −1, −1),
v2 = (−2, 1, 1, 0),
v3 = (1, −1, 1, −1),
v4 = (1, −2, −2, 2). What I want is finding an orthonormal basis without using Gram-Schmidt orthonormalization method. Is there any way to solve this without using Gram-Schmidt method? Can you please show me a way to solve it? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why would you not want to use Gram-Schmidt?

Comment: Because I used it and I'm asked to solve it without using it.

Comment: Note that if those four vectors are linearly independent, then their span is all of ${\bf R}^4$, so any orthonormal basis for ${\bf R}^4$ will do.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Sir, can I right those vectors in matrix form such as 
  \begin{bmatrix}
    2 & -2 & 1 & 1 \\
    -1 & 1 & -1 & -2 \\
    -1 & 1 & 1 & -2 \\
    -1 & 0 & -1 & 2
  \end{bmatrix}
 and then check the rank which is 4. So, they're linearly independent, am I right?

Comment: Yes, if the rank is four, then the vectors are linearly independent.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Yes, the rank is four, I checked it in Matlab. As a result, can I choose orthonormal basis vectors such as (1,0,0,0), (0,1,0,0), (0,0,1,0) and (0,0,0,1). Am I correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your vectors are linearly independent they span the four dimensional space $\mathbb {R^4} $ so the standard orthonormal basis $$\{ (1,0,0,0), (0,1, 0,0),(0,0,1,0), (0,0,0,1)\}$$ will do.